# How to send registration data to server in android?

Tags: android, mysql

it is my login.java
i want to make server register on android

```html
public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

 
  private EditText name,lastName,phoneNumber;
  private Button reg_btn;
  private ProgressDialog pDialog;
  JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
  private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://mojtabaapp.esy.es/register.php";
  private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
  private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
     
     
   
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
  
  // tarif ha
  name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET_name);
  lastName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET_famili);
  phoneNumber=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET_phone);
  reg_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.reg_btn);
  
  reg_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
  
  
 }
 
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
    new CreateUser().execute();
  
 }
 
 class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
  
        boolean failure = false;
  
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("..لطفا کمی صبر کنید");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }
  
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... args){
   
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Check for success tag
           int success;
           String NAME = name.getText().toString();
           String LASTNAME = lastName.getText().toString();
           
           String PHONE=phoneNumber.getText().toString();
           
           try {
               // Building Parameters
               List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", NAME));
               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", LASTNAME));
               
               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", PHONE));

               Log.d("request!", "starting");
               
               //Posting user data to script 
               JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                      LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

               // full json response
               Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

               // json success element
               success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
               if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());               
                finish();
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
               }else{
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                
               }
           } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           return null;
 
   
  }
  
   protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
             // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
             pDialog.dismiss();
             if (file_url != null){
              Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
  
         }
}

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
  // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
  // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
  int id = item.getItemId();
  if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
   return true;
  }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

thats my java code

```js
<?php

require("config.inc.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {
        if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['phone'])) {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "error";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
     $query = " SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = :user";
    $query_params = array(
        ':user' => $_POST['username']
    );
 
    try {
       
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Error";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if ($row) {

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "I'm sorry, this username is already in use";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO users ( username, password , phone ) VALUES ( :user, :pass , :phonenumber) ";

    $query_params = array(
        ':user' => $_POST['username'],
        ':pass' => $_POST['password'], 
        ':phonenumber' => $_POST['phone']
    );
    
    //time to run our query, and create the user
    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
        
        //or just use this use this one:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error2. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Username Successfully Added!";
    echo json_encode($response);

} else {
?>
 <h1>Register</h1> 
 <form action="register.php" method="post"> 
     Username:<br /> 
     <input type="text" name="username" value="" /> 
     <br /><br /> 
     Password:<br /> 
     <input type="password" name="password" value="" /> 
     <br /><br /> 
     <input type="submit" value="Register New User" /> 
 </form>
 <?php
}

?>
```

that's my .php code on host

but my app going to ForceStop
please help me 
where is my problem

i create on database 
username
password 
id
phone

Comment: In your doInBackground() method you are calling  finish(); which I'm pretty sure is ending your activity. You need to post the stack-trace  though if you want help diagnosing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ivan Wooll said you are calling `finish()` in your `doInBackground()` within the if block

```
if (success == 1) { }
```

This means your data is saved successfully using the PHP script and as the status message is returned as 1 due to successful insertion, `finish()` is being called which closes your activity.

Try removing that piece of code from that block.

Hope that helps.